# How to make footer that is only visible on upscrolling

Tags: android, android-layout

I have made a static footer in my home.xml of Android app but I want to make footer for this app instead of making navigation drawer, which only visible after up and down scrolling.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:id="@+id/back_to_previous"
    android:orientation="vertical">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:src="@drawable/selector_footer_services" />
        <com.gaadizo.gaadizo_user.ui.CustomTextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/back_textdf"
            android:hint="Services"
            android:textColorHint="@color/footer_text_inactive"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_13sdp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add scroll change listener to the ScrollView and then in the onScrollChanged method manage the visibility of the footer. Find the sample code below

```
@Override
protected void onScrollChanged(int l, int t, int oldl, int oldt) {
        View view = (View) getChildAt(getChildCount()-1);
        int diff = (view.getBottom()-(getHeight()+getScrollY()));
        if( diff <= 0 ){ 
            yourFooter.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        else{
            yourFooter.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        super.onScrollChanged(l, t, oldl, oldt);
}
```